# Correlating Windows forms textbox text width to GDI width

Tags: c#, gdi, textrenderer

I'm drawing the text from a textbox using GDI; however, I'm trying to create my textbox such that it reflects the same amount of space that I am drawing to in GDI.  So, for some X amount of width in GDI, I would like for the length of the string in the textbox to not be able to exceed this width.

To draw the string in GDI, I'm using the following:

```
Font font = new Font("Lucidia Console", 8, GraphicsUnit.Point);
StringFormat sf = (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone();
g.DrawString(textFromTextbox, font, Brush, layoutRect, sf);
```

As for the textbox, I measure the string as characters are entered:

```
Font font = new Font("Lucidia Console", 8, GraphicsUnit.Point);
Size lineSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textbox.Text, font);
Size charSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(e.KeyChar.ToString(), font);

if( charSize + lineSize > MAX_LINE_SIZE )
 //Other stuff;
```

I have the textbox itself using Lucidia Console 8pt as the font as well.

So, then the trouble becomes making a textbox of X width that's the same width as the width I'm drawing to in GDI.

I've run into all kinds of discussions about glyphs, em-size/pixel ratios, and other topics but with little resolve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

g.DrawString uses GDI+ to draw the text on the screen.

TextRenderer.MeasureText uses GDI.

They are 2 different text rendering models so you will not get the desired results.

There is a Graphics.MeasureString method which is compatible with Graphics.DrawString but I have never gotten it to behave consistently. It might be good enough for your need though, it's worth a try.

Also, there was an article on CodeProject a while back where they drew text onto a bitmap and took a measurement off the bitmap in order to get the exact sizes.  I don't remember the specifics but it shouldn't be hard to find.  The article was about creating a textbox like control in .net only code.

Your other alternative is to use TextRenderer.DrawText to render the text.  That actually does work and matches up nicely with TextRenderer.MeasureText.  If you are doing a lot of measurements though it can be kind of slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) method, which you'll find on your `System.Drawing.Graphics` instance.

Comment: It wasn't entirely clear from your question whether or not it was this bit you're having trouble with. Sorry if I'm pointing out the obvious!

Comment: I almost gave the same answer, but I wasn't really sure what the question was myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to clarify.

For example, if the layoutRectangle that will contain the string I am going to draw is 100 units wide then I want my textbox to not allow for a string that is greater than those 100 units.

I can't seem to find a relationship between the width/units/etc of text inside a Windows form textbox, and the width/units/etc of text drawn in GDI.

Hopefully, this explains it a bit more.

Comment: I was hoping it'd be as simple as finding the with of my string in GDI, and then creating a textbox to that width.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  The width of a string (using the same font and everything as far as I can tell) in a textbox and the width of that same string drawn in GDI aren't the same.